# What is the meaningful difference between" backup/restore" and "detach/attach" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

My question is about difference between "backup & restore" and "detach & attach" in SQL Server.

What is the meaningful difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 0):

**Backup** : SQL Server will create a **.bak** file for you. You can backup/restore your database in sql server using .bak file.

**Attach/Detach** : In attach/detach you can backup/restore your database using **.mdf** and .**ldf** file.